# domain hosting redirect

Tags: html, seo, web-hosting

I have registered a cheap domain (no hosting) and have a web server (AWS). In the domain registration I can forward to the web server. This means that if a user enters my domain they see a **frame** of my website. This means if they click on another page the address still shows my domain but not domain/page. Is there a better way to do this, more SEO friendly as well?

Comment: Sorry, better way to do what exactly? To redirect? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Depends what the domain registrar lets you do. Look for CNAME or A records.

Comment: I am forwarding for now, but I don't like the frames. Yes I think it is the A Record, is it sufficient to set *.domain.com to my IP?

Comment: Change the A record to the site IP that you want them to be able to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing domain you should 301 redirect this new domain to the website.  You may have the option where you chose the frame redirect to do a 301 redirect instead.  If not, you will need to point the domain name at a web host that can do proper redirects for you.

If this is going to be **THE** domain name for your website, you should not redirect to your website.  Rather you should point the DNS "A" record to the IP address that hosts your website.  To make this work you will also need to tell your web host about this.  Your web host will need to add a virtual host for this domain name to serve your website.  Many web hosts let you do this yourself through cpanel or another administrative interface.